# How do I use TextMate as my command line subversion message editor?

Tags: svn, command-line, textmate

Simply setting the SVN_EDITOR variable to "mate" does not get the job done.  It opens TextMate when appropriate, but then when I save the message and exit, I'm prompted to continue, abort or try again.  It seems like the buffer isn't returned to the svn command for use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to include a command line option in your SVN_EDITOR (or EDITOR) variable

export SVN_EDITOR='mate -w'

This makes the svn command wait for the editor to close/release the file before continuing, which is where the process is getting mucked up now.

See [here](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html).

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread googling for textmate as svn editor. While trying I found out that you can also set the editor-cmd in `~/.subversion/config` file and more important you should set the value to `mate -wl1` because in this way the caret will be placed on the first line of the file, the place where to put comments for commit message.

Just my contribute to this thread.